# How to Watermark PDF

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I have a VF page with file upload control ,Users will upload PDF file along with other details and the file will be stored in Attachments.

Requirement : When user uploads PDF then file should be Water Marked with some text OR some custom text should be included in the header/footer of the file and saved in Attachment object.

What are the options available to acheive this functionality ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit the PDF file as this is a binary content. Apex is missing that capability. You have to either build a custom solution outside Salesforce and use it as webservice or you can try some online solution like aspose.com.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I won't be able to use Aspose in my case due to the licensing cost. Do you have any pointers on the other option ( Reading watermarked PDF from external web service and update in attachment object )

Comment: If you know Java you can use iText to create your own web service. Also Heroku may be a good option here.